# cscope: How to disable/remove/escape-from "Change this text string" option

Tags: cscope

Cscope has the following menu options:

```
Find this C symbol:
Find this global definition:
Find functions called by this function:
Find functions calling this function:
Find this text string:
Change this text string:
Find this egrep pattern:
Find this file:
Find files #including this file:
Find assignments to this symbol:
```

Among them, I find the most annoying being the `Change this text string` option. Because whenever I stumble upon it by accident, I am stuck in the `To:` dialog. I cannot break myself out of it. `^C`, `^D`and even `^Z` won't get me out of it. I have to type some garbage and let it start searching before I can use `^Z` to break out of it and kill cscope. And I will lose all my session's history.

In addition, when I actually want to use the feature, only when I am about to apply change, cscope will inform me that I didn't have editor defined so it will not do anything.

So my question is, is there a better way to escape out of the dialog. Or is there a way to disable the option altogether so I don't ended up using it by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If you enter anything at the To: prompt and hit Enter then cscope will list the files on which to apply the change.

At this point you can press Esc to abort the text change.

More here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjaoc/index.html

Comment: The issue is that when working with large code, it will take a long time for cscope to search. During the search, `Esc` does not work. As I mentioned earlier, only way out I found is `^Z` and kill it.